# Rxjs : Retry http call with updated parameters if no results

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I am a novice with **Rxjs**, I'm trying to do a request to my API with limits passed in parameters.
My problem is sometimes the returned result is empty for some reasons. The thing I need to do is retry this API call with updated parameters (skip param)

```
pollService.getPoll$(skip, limit).subscribe((pollList) => {        
    doStuff;
},
(error) => {
    doStuff;
});
```

I read some topics about the **RetryWhen** RXJS function but it is about errors when the request fail and you want to retry the same one but I ve no errors and I don't want to retry the same request, I also saw topics about **Replay** function but it is not very clear to me.

Can someone explain me what to do here please !!

Thanks

Alex

Comment: How many do you wish to repeat the request and do you wish to keep retrying until it returns a valid response?

Comment: @Michael D : I want repeat the request until i got 2 items in my response datas.

Comment: Your result is empty (Emits nothing) or there's no result (Emits, but there's not payload)? Those two would have different solutions

Comment: The result is emmited, but it is empty cause the backend removed items from the result list for some funtionnal reasons, thats why i need to call API with different parameters to fetch other results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider utilizing the [expand](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/expand) operator as demonstrated below:

```
 import { EMPTY, of } from "rxjs"
 import { expand } from "rxjs/operators"
```

```js
 public startPolling(skip: number, limit: number): void {
    of([])
       .pipe(
           expand(x => x.length < 2 ? pollService.getPoll$(skip--, limit) : EMPTY)
        )
       .subscribe(pollList => {})
 }
```

**Update:**

```
public poll = (skip: number, limit: number): void => {
  defer(() => getPoll$(1 + skip--, limit))
    .pipe(
      repeat(),
      first(x => {
        if(x.length < 2){
          // update some variable in the component
          return false;
        }

        return true;
      })
    )
    .subscribe(pollList => { })
}
```

Comment: Hello Rafi and thanks a lot for your answer, the problem is now when I test your answer the skip value is set to -1 for the first request so i Have to initialize to a fake value, the other question I have is : in the expand I would to do more things, and update some variables in my component before call my pollService.getPoll$(skip--, limit), is it possible to do this ?

Comment: It works like a charm !! thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your backend is paging data using the `skip` and `limit` parameters.

So, if you have a `skip` value that is too high, you want to reduce it automatically.

There are many, many ways to solve this problem in RxJS:

- you could insert a `switchMap` after `getPoll$`. `SwitchMap` would return a new observable, either wrapping the result if it's ok (with `of(pollList)`), or returning `pollService.getPoll$(newSkipValue, newLimitValue)`
- you could `map` the result and throw an Error if the result doesn't pass validation. Then you could `catchError` and return the result of a new call to `getPoll$`

However, what I suggest is modelling the call differently. I would use a `Subject` as a source of requests, and `switchMap` to execute the requests.

```js
// inside the component or service
interface GetPollRequest {
  skip: number;
  limit: number;
}

private _callSource = new Subject<GetPollRequest>();

public triggerCall(skip: number, limit: number) {
  this._callSource.next({skip, limit});
}

constructor(...) {
  this._callSource.pipe(
    // every time _callSource emits, we call the server
    switchMap(({skip, limit) => pollService.getPoll$(skip, limit).pipe(
      map(pollList => ({ pollList, skip, limit }))
    ),
    tap(({pollList, skip, limit}) => {
      // update the request in any way you need. You need to make sure
      // that the next automatic trigger doesn't repeat indefinitely,
      // or you'll simulate a DOS attack to your backend
      if (pollList.length < 2) this.triggerCall(skip - 2, limit);
    })
  ).subscribe(pollList => // update the component status);
}
```

Using this pattern, you use subjects as triggers (or custom events, they are pretty much the same), and you wrap them up during constructor time.

`SwitchMap` is used to create an observable (in this case, performing a request) every time the source emits.
`Tap` is used to perform an operation (pretty much like a subscribe), embedded in the chain of transformations inside the pipe.

Comment: Hello @A. Chiesa and thank you a lot to take time to answer my question. I am a bit lost with your answer because I understand what you say but the code does not compile and the syntax in rxjs is a bit difficult to get for a novice ^^. The thing what I want to do is : I want to skip data that I dont want to display (when the backend reply an empty array) I want to do a new call with skip+=2 to get next datas and update some variables in my component. I think your answer is a good way but my compiler says switchMap is deprecated and does not accept the subscribe at the end of your code.

Comment: @AltoDev you should try building a Stackblitz example of your code, so is it possible for anyone to look in it and check what's going on. I know that the initial impact with RxJS is very (and I mean, _very_) hard, but trust me, it is worth it. You learn operators one at a time, and the most difficult part in learning them is why and when you should use one or the other.